# Pluralize Swedish Words?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to use `PluralizationService` to pluralize swedish words?

I tried to use PluralizationService but i got exception that it only supports english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create your own version of the `PluralizationService` that supports Swedish. Create a derived class that inherits from `PluralizationService` and override the methods there to provide the functionality. There does not seem to be a built-in service that supports Swedish. Once this is done, set the new service on the `EntityModelSchemaGenerator.PluralizationService` property.

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/12/02/pluralization.aspx) explains the process pretty well.

As you may or may not know, it's a bit tricky to pluralize words in Swedish since there is a gender system on nouns which is basically irregular. For instance:

- Monkey -> Monkeys is Apa -> Apor
- Banana -> Bananas is Banan -> Bananer
- Deer -> Deers is Hjort -> Hjortar

So, the linguistic rules are a bit of effort to make right, and there's a plethora of special cases everywhere like Fot -> Fötter (coincidentally, also a special case in English with foot -> feet).